# Algolia: search - show featured items on top of page

Tags: algolia

Is it possible to construct order criteria in that way that all featured items goes always on top of the page ? I would like to performe this in single search call.

Answer (score 0):

Algolia allows you sort your results. If your records have this "featured" attribute indexed, you can ad it to your formula.

Please find the doc here: https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/relevance/sorting/

I also recommend you to have a look at the Custom ranking feature https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/relevance/ranking/#custom-ranking